# Disk storage files in wsl2. Where does free space disappear?

Tags: docker, size, wsl-2

Earlier I used with hyper-v and docker.

Recently I've installed wsl2 for docker usage.
After wsl2 installation I dowloaded and installed ubuntu 20 and set it in docker desktop settings.

So command `wsl --list returns`

```
-* Ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
-  docker-desktop         Running         2
-  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

I see in daily work that free space disappears on disk C.
I found few files with huge size and i'd like to know what it is? And if I could delete them or cut?

Here are the files:

```
c:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx-----------55 gb
c:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx--------45 gb
c:\Users\All Users\DockerDesktop\vm-data\DockerDesktop.vhdx----the same as prev. What is it??
```

General question - how reduce disk usage? And what are that files?

Comment: These are the actual files of the Docker containers, their storage and everything else. You should probably not delete them, but delete any unwanted containers from the Docker application.

What is a mystery to me, though, is why the file from ProgramData is duplicated in All Users. It is the same on my machine, but can't find out why.

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same issue: wsl2 got bigger and bigger and even when I deleted files inside of wsl2, I **couldn't see the free space** reflected on my host machine.

After some research I found a nice step-by-step instruction by Stephen Rees-Carter how to shrink the used space by wsl2: [How to Shrink a WSL2 Virtual Disk](https://stephenreescarter.net/how-to-shrink-a-wsl2-virtual-disk/)

A rough explanation:

- wsl2 is compressed in one single image on your host machine called `ext4.vhdx` (located somewhere `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<Distro>\LocalState`)
- to shrink that file and return unused space `diskpart` can be used:

  - `select vdisk file="pathTo_ext4.vhdx"`
  - `compact vdisk`

In my case the wsl2 image size was reduced by **~30%**.

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by compacting the `vhdx` file through `diskpart`

Below file eats up a lot of diskspace.

`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx`

Here are the commands to resolve and reclaim your diskspace

1. Ensure that your docker data is cleaned up

   - `docker system prune -all`
   - *Warning*: Deletes all your images, container, volumes and all data that's created by docker
2. Terminate the `wsl` dist that's unused.

   - Run the command `wsl -l -v` and terminate all other entries except the below

     - Entry with `*` represents your current dist
     - `docker-desktop`
     - `docker-desktop-data`
3. Take the backup of you current dist `wsl --export <dist> <path>`
4. `diskpart`

   1. Opens up a new prompt `DISKPART>`. Issue the command `select vdisk file="your-docker-data-file"`

      - Example: `select vdisk file="C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data"`
   2. Finally, do `compact vdisk`
      [image: DiskPart successfully compacted the virtual disk file]